# location service android source code boolean gps and network lines meaning

Tags: java, android

what does these lines mean :

boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want just meaning of those lines:

**boolean isGPSEnabled = false;**

It simply means a variable **isGPSEnabled** of type boolean which is initialised with a value i.e. *false*

Similarly, there are 2 other variables isNetworkEnabled and canGetLocation which are set to *false*.

Well as i can see the tag of **Android** in your question:

So, some other things, as you didn't provided complete information but those **variables are generally used to enable location service in an android app**, as like if I want to check whether **GPS is Enabled or not and Network provider is Enabled or not.**